# Specify different times for Monday-Saturday and Sunday in single CRON statement

Tags: cron, cronexpression

I need to run a job at this `cron` schedule, but it seems like I can't express this in one statement. Is there a way to get this in one `cron` statement?

8am Mon-Sat

2pm Sun

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right. I'm afraid this is not possible. You'll need to specify two CRON expressions.